# Local notification on webpage update in webview that runs in background - Android

Tags: android, webview, notifications

I am currently using GCM to send notifications from web server to Android app, but I want to stop using GCM and examine the local notification idea instead.

My app has a webview and my idea is that this webview will somehow run in the BG and when the web page in the webview will be updated, the webview will wake up and generate a local notification on the device. This way, I don't have to send notifications. I just need to update the page from my server and the user will get a local notification.

Is there a way to do that? How? Anyone knows a tutorial or example for that?

Thank you